# What class is used for keyword 'synchronized'?

Tags: java, multithreading

In C#, [lock keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) is equivalent to [Monitor.Enter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/de0542zz(v=vs.110).aspx) and Leave().

In Java, What is the equivalent one to [synchronized keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)?

Answer (score 6):

The `synchronized` keyword makes use of JVM internals in its implementation. This is not exposed as a class.

There are additional (more powerful) synchronization primitives in the java.util.concurrent package. These do not use language keywords, but are used as classes, such as [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html). They in turn make use of [`sun.misc.Unsafe#park`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534489/unsafe-park-vs-object-wait), but you are not supposed to need to know about that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then, are you using try-finally block instead of synchronized block?

Comment: Depends. Usually, you would. But these locks are quite flexible. You could conceivably pass them around so that lock acquistion and release don't have to happen in the same stack frame/method.